# How to set the encrypted Flag for an Outlook MailItem?

Tags: c#, encryption, outlook, vsto

I need to be able to programmatically send encrypted password Emails with an Excel VSTO Add-In so i have written this static method to send Outlook Emails:

```
private static Outlook.Application outlookApp;
private const string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";

public static void SendPasswordEmail(string emailAddress, string password, string subject, bool PGP)
        {
            GetOutlookApp();
            Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Check if the Email should be prepared to be sent with PGP or PKI encryption.
            if (PGP)
            {
                eMail.Subject = String.Concat("PGP: ", subject);
            }
            else
            {
                eMail.Subject = subject;
                // Set the Security Flags of the current MailItem to encrypted.
                // already tried 1,2
                eMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("PR_SECURITY_FLAGS", 1);
            }
            String eMailBody = String.Format(@Properties.Resources.PasswordEmailBody, password);
            eMail.To = emailAddress;
            eMail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            eMail.HTMLBody = eMailBody;
            eMail.Send();
        }
```

i am using this method to get the Outlook Application:

```
private static void GetOutlookApp()
        {
            // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
            {
                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                outlookApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
            }
            else
            {
                // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and sign in to the default profile.
                outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace session = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                session.Logon("", "", false, true);
            }
        }
```

But i cant seem to set the security flag of the MailItem to encrypted. No Exception thrown ! it just that outlook doesn't send the Email as encrypted !

i have this VBA Code which is working fine:

```
Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
Dim prop As Long

Set MailItem = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MailItem.To = something
MailItem.Subject = something
MailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
MailItem.Body = something

// set encrypted flag
Set MailItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
prop = CLng(MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GETPROPERTY(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS))
ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H1 ' SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED
MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, ulFlags
MailItem.SEND
```

can you please explain to me what is this code block doing exactly?

```
Set MailItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
prop = CLng(MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GETPROPERTY(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS))
ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H1 ' SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED
MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, ulFlags
```

Is there a refrence or a List of the available MAPI properties and their accepted values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a DASL name of the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS property, not a property name. For example:

```
private const string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";
eMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, 1);
```

See [How to sign or encrypt a message programmatically from OOM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2009/03/16/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom/) for more information.

Comment: oh that explains it , i can't believe i missed this but i am still curious about this VBA Code what is it doing ?
ulFlags = ulFlags Or &H1 ' SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED

Comment: The code adds the encrypted flag/marker to the existing ones